# Azure Data Factory FTP as Sink Not Supported

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a link service to my FTP Server
[image]

I am now trying to use the FTP server as sink, however, it would appear Azure Data Factory does not support FTP Server as a sink, i.e. it's not possible to copy data to a FTP server, but it is possible to copy to SFTP server.

Can someone confirm if the above statement is correct?

By way of an update. When I attempt to select ftp as a sink I only get SFTP as an option
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Azure Data Factory does not support FTP Server as a sink. It is only possible to copy data to an SFTP server. Here is the list of supported [connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview) in Azure Data Factory, Azure Synapse Analytics.

[image]